# Can't create folder using DateTime as name

Tags: java, file

I am trying to create a folder using a TimeStamp as the folder name. The code I am using will not create the folder when I use the timeStamp variable in the code below. However if I set the folder name directly like this ...

```
File dir = new File("Hello")
```

The folder is created. Is this the right way to set a folder name using Date and time?

```
public void logEmData(String reason,Campus c ) throws IOException 
{

    LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.now();

    try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true))
    {
        writer.write("Building " + c.getName() + " Entered Emergency Mode" + System.lineSeparator());

        writer.write(" Reason: " + reason + System.lineSeparator());

        writer.write(time.toString() + System.lineSeparator());

       //Create folder 
        String timeStamp = "EM_" + time;
        File dir = new File(timeStamp);
        dir.mkdir();

    }
```

Comment: `LocalDateTime` could contain `/` or \ and `:` characters, which would be illegal characters for a folder name (under Windows at least)

Comment: @MadProgrammer To create `\`` character try to escape it with ``\`` like `\`\\`\``. OR to create ``\`` you need to surround it with two `\`\`` like `\`\`\\`\`` (damn it I was too late).

Answer (score 4):

`LocalDateTime.now()` gets you a date with a format roughly like so: `2015-01-14T16:00:49.455`.

`:` is a problematic character for folder creation under Windows due to it being a [reserved character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#naming_conventions). You may want to consider formatting the string to change it to `-`.

Comment: On Unix both `:` and `.` are valid characters for paths. Windows forbids `:` but `.` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Most date formats contain characters that Windows will choke on, particularly `MM/dd/yyyy` (`\`) or anything that includes the time (`:`).

The best approach, which also has the advantage of sorting lexically, is to use the ISO-8601 format of `YYYY-MM-dd`, or if you absolutely need time information, using underscores as separators instead of colons.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java NIO2 for this purposes.

```
Files.createDirectory(Paths.get("path-to-dir"));
```

I think it will help. And use custom formatting for date such as MM-dd-yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

The `LocalDateTime.now.toString()` produces a String like:

```
2018-01-01T00:00:00.000
```

On Windows this is not a valid directory name, because the `:` char is not permitted on directory names.

So, you can remove the `:` or replace with something else:

```
 String directoryName = LocalDateTime.now.toString().replaceAll(":", "");
```